# Game Center Security? iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, security, sdk, center

After hearing about the hacker who made the exploit to send any game center score I was wondering if anyone maybe had a solution to this. As far as it seems I think before the app sends the score it intercepts it and changes the value then it sends the leaderboard. So I was wondering if maybe we could come up with a solution to stop people from intercepting it?
Thanks

Comment: You don't have to. Apple has to improve it in their next SDK release.

Answer (score 3):

This cannot be done. If the hacker intercepts the data being sent to the server, he has access to and can change it. I suspected Game Center doesn't have any kind of encryption algorithm, and my suspicions were confirmed.
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/69773-game-center-hack-now-anyway-stop.html